# assigning an object to 1 entry of a pandas dataframe with 2 methods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I would like to share a strange behavior of pandas, and find out the reason :
I assign a numpy array as an object to 1 element (cell, entry) of a pandas dataframe in 2 different ways :

first create a sample dataframe :

```py
rn = np.random.randint(1 , 100, size=(4,2))  #  random numbers

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rn , columns=['a' , 'b' ])

df['b'] = df['b'].astype(object)  # setting 1 column's data-type as 'object'.

c = np.array([1,4,4])    # I want to put this in 1 entry of the dataframe :
```

method 1 :

```py
df['b'].loc[0] = c
```

successful, but there is a warning :

SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

method 2 :

```py
df.loc[0 , 'b'] = c
```

unsuccessful with the following error :

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quirk (not to say an inconsistency) in Pandas indexing. It sees one single *slot* on the left side of the assignation and an iterable of 3 values on the right side and chokes on that.

The only way I have found is to force Pandas to use an index:

```
df.loc[0:0, 'b' ] = pd.Series([c], [0])
```

It gives neither error nor warning and you can control the result:

```
print(type(df.loc[0, 'b']), df, sep='\n')
```

which gives as expected:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    a          b
0  45  [1, 4, 4]
1  65         68
2  68         10
3  84         22
```

Rather hacky, but at least provides the expected behaviour...